# How to wrap multiple different innerhtml values at once in a variable

Tags: javascript, performance, innerhtml

I'm working on a international country code selection section for my project and for that I have used innerHTML to inject the SVG flag icons of every country (within a SPAN tag) in every option. and the problem I'm facing is that innerHTML is super slow and that is slowed down my website performance.

Because the Option tag does not support any other HTML tag, that's why I have created a div tag for every single option or country (using JS) to render the country flag. and for that I have used the innerHTML upto 240 times for 240 countries. which decreased my page loading speed upto 3-4 seconds.

Is there are any way to wrap all the innerHTML in a single variable so that we can declear it once only, that speed up the performance of my site.

**Please have a look on my JS Snippet.**

```js
  // Autoclick on the parent div to hide the Dropdown after loading a page (Bug)
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.querySelector(".country-code-selector").click();
  });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

      const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      const link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.type = 'text/css';
      link.href = 'https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css';
      head.appendChild(link);

      // Get dropdowns and form
      const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('[cc-data-dropdown]');
      const form = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector form');

      // Check if dropdowns exist on page
      if (dropdowns.length > 0) {
          // Loop through dropdowns and create custom dropdown for each select element
          dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
              createCustomDropdown(dropdown);
          });
      }

      // Check if form element exist on page
      if (form !== null) {
          // When form is submitted console log the value of the select field
          form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log('Selected country:', form.querySelector('[name="country"]').value);
          });
      }

      // Create custom dropdown
      function createCustomDropdown(dropdown) {
          // Get all options and convert them from nodelist to array
          const options = dropdown.querySelectorAll('option');
          const optionsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(options);

          optionsArr[0].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+69)';
          optionsArr[1].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-alb"></span> Albania (+355)';
          optionsArr[2].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dza"></span> Algeria (+213)';
          optionsArr[3].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-asm"></span> American Samoa (+1-684)';
          optionsArr[4].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-and"></span> Andorra (+376)';
          optionsArr[5].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ago"></span> Angola (+244)';
          optionsArr[6].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aia"></span> Anguilla (+1-264)';
          optionsArr[7].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ata"></span> Antarctica (+672)';
          optionsArr[8].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-atg"></span> Antigua and Barbuda (+1-268)';
          optionsArr[9].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-arg"></span> Argentina (+54)';
          optionsArr[10].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-arm"></span> Armenia (+374)';
          optionsArr[11].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-abw"></span> Aruba (+297)';
          optionsArr[12].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aus"></span> Australia (+61)';
          optionsArr[13].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aut"></span> Austria (+43)';
          optionsArr[14].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aze"></span> Azerbaijan (+994)';
          optionsArr[15].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bhs"></span> Bahamas (+1-242)';
          optionsArr[16].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bhr"></span> Bahrain (+973)';
          optionsArr[17].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)';
          optionsArr[18].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-brb"></span> Barbados (+1-246)';
          optionsArr[19].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-blr"></span> Belarus (+375)';
          optionsArr[20].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bel"></span> Belgium (+32)';
          optionsArr[21].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-blz"></span> Belize (+501)';
          optionsArr[22].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ben"></span> Benin (+229)';
          optionsArr[23].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bmu"></span> Bermuda (+1-441)';
          optionsArr[24].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-btn"></span> Bhutan (+975)';
          optionsArr[25].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bol"></span> Bolivia (+591)';
          optionsArr[26].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bih"></span> Bosnia and Herzegovina (+387)';
          optionsArr[27].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bwa"></span> Botswana (+267)';
          optionsArr[28].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bra"></span> Brazil (+55)';
          optionsArr[29].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-iot"></span> British Indian Ocean Territory (+246)';
          optionsArr[30].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-vgb"></span> British Virgin Islands (+1-284)';
          optionsArr[31].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-brn"></span> Brunei (+673)';
          optionsArr[32].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgr"></span> Bulgaria (+359)';
          optionsArr[33].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bfa"></span> Burkina Faso (+226)';
          optionsArr[34].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bdi"></span> Burundi (+257)';
          optionsArr[35].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-khm"></span> Cambodia (+855)';
          optionsArr[36].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cmr"></span> Cameroon (+237)';
          optionsArr[37].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-can"></span> Canada (+1)';
          optionsArr[38].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cpv"></span> Cape Verde (+238)';
          optionsArr[39].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cym"></span> Cayman Islands (+1-345)';
          optionsArr[40].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-caf"></span> Central African Republic (+236)';
          optionsArr[41].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-tcd"></span> Chad (+235)';
          optionsArr[42].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-chl"></span> Chile (+56)';
          optionsArr[43].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-chn"></span> China (+86)';
          optionsArr[44].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cxr"></span> Christmas Island (+61)';
          optionsArr[45].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cck"></span> Cocos Islands (+61)';
          optionsArr[46].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-col"></span> Colombia (+57)';
          optionsArr[47].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-com"></span> Comoros (+269)';
          optionsArr[48].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cok"></span> Cook Islands (+682)';
          optionsArr[49].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cri"></span> Costa Rica (+506)';
          optionsArr[50].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-hrv"></span> Croatia (+385)';
          optionsArr[51].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cub"></span> Cuba (+53)';
          optionsArr[52].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cuw"></span> Curacao (+599)';
          optionsArr[53].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cyp"></span> Cyprus (+357)';
          optionsArr[54].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cze"></span> Czech Republic (+420)';
          optionsArr[55].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cod"></span> Democratic Republic of the Congo (+243)';
          optionsArr[56].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dnk"></span> Denmark (+45)';
          optionsArr[57].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dji"></span> Djibouti (+253)';
          optionsArr[58].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dma"></span> Dominica (+1-767)';
          optionsArr[59].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dom"></span> Dominican Republic (+1-809)';
          optionsArr[60].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-tls"></span> East Timor (+670)';
          optionsArr[61].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ecu"></span> Ecuador (+593)';
          optionsArr[62].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-egy"></span> Egypt (+20)';
          optionsArr[63].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-slv"></span> El Salvador (+503)';
          optionsArr[64].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gnq"></span> Equatorial Guinea (+240)';
          optionsArr[65].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eri"></span> Eritrea (+291)';
          optionsArr[66].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-est"></span> Estonia (+372)';
          optionsArr[67].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eth"></span> Ethiopia (+251)';
          optionsArr[68].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-flk"></span> Falkland Islands (+500)';
          optionsArr[69].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fro"></span> Faroe Islands (+298)';
          optionsArr[70].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fji"></span> Fiji (+679)';
          // More 169 Countries (Currently not added here to shortner the code) -
          optionsArr[71].innerHTML = 'No Data Found';


          // Create custom dropdown element and add class dropdown to it
          // Insert it in the DOM after the select field
          const customDropdown = document.createElement('div');
          customDropdown.classList.add('cc-dropdown');
          dropdown.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', customDropdown);

          // Create element for selected option
          // Add class to this element, text from the first option in select field and append it to custom dropdown
          const selected = document.createElement('div');
          selected.classList.add('cc-dropdown-selected');
          selected.innerHTML = 'Tel-Code';
          customDropdown.appendChild(selected);

          // Create element for dropdown menu, add class to it and append it to custom dropdown
          // Add click event to selected element to toggle dropdown menu
          const menu = document.createElement('div');
          menu.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu');
          customDropdown.appendChild(menu);
          selected.addEventListener('click', toggleDropdown.bind(menu));

          // Create serach input element
          // Add class, type and placeholder to this element and append it to menu element
          const search = document.createElement('input');
          search.placeholder = 'Search Your Country...';
          search.type = 'text';
          search.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-search');
          menu.appendChild(search);

          // Create wrapper element for menu items, add class to it and append to menu element
          const menuItemsWrapper = document.createElement('div');
          menuItemsWrapper.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-items');
          menu.appendChild(menuItemsWrapper);

          // Loop through all options and create custom option for each option and append it to items wrapper element
          // Add click event for each custom option to set clicked option as selected option
          optionsArr.forEach(option => {
              const item = document.createElement('div');
              item.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-item');
              item.dataset.value = option.value;
              item.innerHTML = option.innerHTML;
              menuItemsWrapper.appendChild(item);

              item.addEventListener('click', setSelected.bind(item, selected, dropdown, menu));
          });

          // Add selected class to first custom option
          // menuItemsWrapper.querySelector('div').classList.add('selected');

          // Add input event to search input element to filter items
          // Add click event to document element to close custom dropdown if clicked outside of it
          // Hide original dropdown(select)
          search.addEventListener('input', filterItems.bind(search, optionsArr, menu));
          document.addEventListener('click', closeIfClickedOutside.bind(customDropdown, menu));
          dropdown.style.display = 'none';

      }


      // Toggle dropdown
      function toggleDropdown() {
          // Check if dropdown is opened and if it is close it, otherwise open it and focus search input

          if (this.offsetParent !== null) {
              this.style.display = 'none';
          } else {
              this.style.display = 'block';
              this.querySelector('input').focus();
          }
      }

      // Set selected option
      function setSelected(selected, dropdown, menu) {
          // Get value and label from clicked custom option
          const value = this.dataset.value;
          const label = this.innerHTML;

          // Change the text on selected element
          // Change the value on select field  

          filterDate = /(<span\b[^<>]*><\/span>\s*)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\((\+[\d-]+)\)/g;
          selected.innerHTML = label.replace(filterDate, `$1$2`);
          dropdown.value = value;

          // Close the menu
          // Reset search input value
          // Remove selected class from previously selected option and show all divs if they were filtered
          // Add selected class to clicked option
          menu.style.display = 'none';
          menu.querySelector('input').value = '';
          menu.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
              if (div.classList.contains('selected')) {
                  div.classList.remove('selected');
              }
              if (div.offsetParent === null) {
                  div.style.display = 'block';
              }
          });
          this.classList.add('selected');
      }

      // Filter items
      function filterItems(itemsArr, menu) {
          // Get all custom options
          // Get the value of search input and convert it to all lowercase characters
          // Get filtered items
          // Get the indexes of filtered items
          const customOptions = menu.querySelectorAll('.cc-dropdown-menu-items div');
          const value = this.value.toLowerCase();
          const filteredItems = itemsArr.filter(item => item.value.toLowerCase().includes(value));
          const indexesArr = filteredItems.map(item => itemsArr.indexOf(item));

          // Check if option is not inside indexes array and hide it and if it is inside indexes array and it is hidden show it


          var options = itemsArr.length;
          itemsArr.forEach(option => {
              if (!indexesArr.includes(itemsArr.indexOf(option))) {
                  customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].style.display = 'none';
                  options -= 1;
                  if (options <= 0) {
                      customOptions[itemsArr.length - 1].style.display = 'block';
                  }
              } else {
                  if (customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].offsetParent === null) {
                      customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].style.display = 'block';
                  }
              }
          });
      }

      // Close dropdown if clicked outside dropdown element
      function closeIfClickedOutside(menu, e) {
          if (e.target.closest('.cc-dropdown') === null && e.target !== this && menu.offsetParent !== null) {
              menu.style.display = 'none';
          }
      }


  });
```

```css
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
     background-color: #323757;
     width: 2px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar {
     background-color: #323757;
     width: 14px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     background-color: #e8576f;
     border: 4px solid #323757;
     z-index: -1;
     width: 2px;
     min-height: 50px;
}
 #phone-number {
     width: calc(100% - 120px);
     margin-left: 120px;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox .tx {
     margin-left: 120px;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox {
     display: flex;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox .ln {
     margin-left: 120px;
     width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
 .cc-dropdown {
     position: relative;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 116px;
     height: 40px;
     padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: box-shadow .3s ease;
     background-color: #323757;
     border-radius: 3px;
     font-size: 15px;
     color: #fff;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected::after {
     top: calc(50% - 2px);
     right: 10px;
     border: solid transparent;
     content: '';
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     border-top-color:#000;
     border-width: 4px;
     margin-left: -4px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected:hover {
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu {
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     left: 0;
     width: 273px;
     border: 3px solid #323757;
     margin-right: -2px;
     border-top: 0;
     background-color: #fff;
     z-index: +9;
     margin-top: 10px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items {
     max-height: 200px;
     width: 270px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     z-index: +9;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-search {
     display: block;
     width: 260px;
     border: 0;
     border-right: 3px solid #323757;
     padding: 14px 0px 14px 10px;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: 550;
     color: #fff;
     outline: 0;
     background-color: #323757;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-search::placeholder {
     color: rgb(214, 214, 214)!important;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item {
     width: 267px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #323757a6;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: 550;
     cursor: pointer;
     z-index: +9;
     user-select: none;
     padding: 10px 18px 10px 10px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items .flag-icon {
     height: 15px;
     width: 26px;
     margin-right: 3px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:last-child {
     border-bottom: 0;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
     background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected {
     border: none;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected .flag-icon {
     margin-right: 5px!important;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected, .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected:hover {
     background-color: #323757c2;
     color: #ffffff;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:last-child {
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="country-code-selector">
   <form class="cc-form">
      <div class="cc-form-group">
         <select id="country" name="country" cc-data-dropdown>
            <option value="Afganistan"></option>
            <option value="Albania"></option>
            <option value="Algeria"></option>
            <option value="American Samoa"></option>
            <option value="Andorra"></option>
            <option value="Angola"></option>
            <option value="Anguilla"></option>
            <option value="Antarctica"></option>
            <option value="Antigua and Barbuda"></option>
            <option value="Argentina"></option>
            <option value="Armenia"></option>
            <option value="Aruba"></option>
            <option value="Australia"></option>
            <option value="Austria"></option>
            <option value="Azerbaijan"></option>
            <option value="Bahamas"></option>
            <option value="Bahrain"></option>
            <option value="Bangladesh"></option>
            <option value="Barbados"></option>
            <option value="Belarus"></option>
            <option value="Belgium"></option>
            <option value="Belize"></option>
            <option value="Benin"></option>
            <option value="Bermuda"></option>
            <option value="Bhutan"></option>
            <option value="Bolivia"></option>
            <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina"></option>
            <option value="Botswana"></option>
            <option value="Brazil"></option>
            <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory"></option>
            <option value="British Virgin Islands"></option>
            <option value="Brunei"></option>
            <option value="Bulgaria"></option>
            <option value="Burkina Faso"></option>
            <option value="Burundi"></option>
            <option value="Cambodia"></option>
            <option value="Cameroon"></option>
            <option value="Canada"></option>
            <option value="Cape Verde"></option>
            <option value="Cayman Islands"></option>
            <option value="Central African Republic"></option>
            <option value="Chad"></option>
            <option value="Chile"></option>
            <option value="China"></option>
            <option value="Christmas Island"></option>
            <option value="Cocos Islands"></option>
            <option value="Colombia"></option>
            <option value="Comoros"></option>
            <option value="Cook Islands"></option>
            <option value="Costa Rica"></option>
            <option value="Croatia"></option>
            <option value="Cuba"></option>
            <option value="Curacao"></option>
            <option value="Cyprus"></option>
            <option value="Czech Republic"></option>
            <option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo"></option>
            <option value="Denmark"></option>
            <option value="Djibouti"></option>
            <option value="Dominica"></option>
            <option value="Dominican Republic"></option>
            <option value="East Timor"></option>
            <option value="Ecuador"></option>
            <option value="Egypt"></option>
            <option value="El Salvador"></option>
            <option value="Equatorial Guinea"></option>
            <option value="Eritrea"></option>
            <option value="Estonia"></option>
            <option value="Ethiopia"></option>
            <option value="Falkland Islands"></option>
            <option value="Faroe Islands"></option>
            <option value="Fiji"></option>
            <option></option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How about a CSS oriented approach? You could apply your flags as `background-image` on `:before` pseudo-selectors

Comment: Not working Sir